# Is there a way to turn a single row from a DB2 SQL statement result set into multiple rows based on one value from that resulting row?

Tags: sql, join, db2, common-table-expression, cross-join

If I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT A.W, A.X, B.Y, B.Z 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.value1 = B.value2;
```

Which is returning a row like this:

```
 W | X | Y | Z
---+---+---+--
 w | x | y | z
```

Is there a way to modify that statement so the result will be something like this table

```
 W | X | Y1  | Y2  | Z
---+---+-----+-----+---
 w | x | y+0 | y+1 | z
 w | x | y+2 | y+3 | z
 w | x | y+4 | y+5 | z
 w | x | y+6 | y+7 | z
 w | x | y+8 | y+9 | z
```

where the `Y1` and `Y2` columns are derived from the original `y` value

Comment: Do you want to get 5 output rows per each original one? What if  there are no corresponding row in B? Do you want to get all NULLs in Yx then?

Comment: Yes, there should be 5 output rows for each result, and in my scenario there will always be a corresponding row in B.

Comment: If there is always a row in B then yo should change to INNER JOIN.

Comment: In my actual SQL statement it is actually an `INNER JOIN`, I'll update the question to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns the integers 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8 and cross join it to your query:

```
WITH cte(n) AS (VALUES (0), (2), (4), (6), (8))
SELECT A.W, A.X, 
       B.Y + c.n AS Y1,
       B.Y + c.n + 1 AS Y2, 
       B.Z 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.value1 = B.value2
CROSS JOIN  cte AS c;
```

If you want a dynamic set of integers use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte(n) AS (
  SELECT 0 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 2 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE n < 8 -- change 8 to the number that you want
)
SELECT A.W, A.X, 
       B.Y + c.n AS Y1,
       B.Y + c.n + 1 AS Y2, 
       B.Z 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.value1 = B.value2
CROSS JOIN  cte AS c;
```

Comment: This worked in a simplified example, but in the query I'm trying to adapt it to, I'm getting this error: `SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "SELECT <table>.<pkId>" was found following "2), (4), (6), (8))\n". Expected tokens may include: "<join_operand>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53`

Comment: @devjoco I don't have your actual code. You will have to adapt my query to your query.

Comment: Found the issue, my SQL had a `WHERE` clause, and I tacked the `CROSS JOIN` onto it after this instead of before it. Working just fine now, thank you